# Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue

Tags: 12.04, boot

```
Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue...
```

The error message appears immediately after the boot screen on purple background. Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Have you tried pressing a key to continue? Also, is this on the installation CD or after you install?

Comment: [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784) might help.

Comment: After pressing a key, booting is continuing, even with pressing no key after few seconds. It's after install.

Comment: If it continues to boot, there really is no serious problem, is there? "If it ain't[sic] broke, don't fix it!"

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04.4 there's no line saying save_env `recordfail` There's one saying just `recordfail`.
Shall I delete it anyway?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1285098:

Press <kbd>E</kbd> at the GRUB menu. Find the line saying `save_env recordfail` and delete all of it with the <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot, and then open the Terminal by searching it in the dash(launcher menu).

Run the following command, and then when it asks for your password, type it, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your password will not be shown, not even asterisks.

```
sudo -i
```

Then, run each command, *one-by-one*.

```
cd /boot/grub
rm grubenv
grub-editenv grubenv create
grub-editenv grubenv set default=0
grub-editenv grubenv list
update-grub
```

The second-to-last command should show `default=0`. If it does, run the last command, and let it finish. When it finishes, you should get the prompt `/boot/grub#` or something like that again(it's what you see after each command). Run `exit` twice, and then reboot.

Comment: How do I find the GRUB menu? Must I create sudo passwd root for sudo -i?

Comment: The GRUB menu can be found by holding Shift while the system is in the early stages of booting (right through BIOS). The password you give to `sudo -i` is your USER password, not the root password.

Comment: in my boot configuration there is only one line saying `recordfail`. I deleted it but still can't get it to boot up

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I know it's probably too late for you, but I just had the same problem as you. The options seem to have changed slightly in 14.04. I used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to get it to a state where it boots past the error message, and then followed the above instructions to permanently remove the error itself.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Same problem with my boot configurations. Anything you tried which worked for you? Please help...

Comment: it show default=0, with last command, /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'aufs'

Comment: I can confirm this still works on Ubuntu 20.04.2. I was using ZFS, don't know if that maybe caused the issue. Anyway, it was only necessary to run the mentioned commands from /boot/grub directory. I didn't need to delete `save_env recordfail` nor `did I get the /boot/grub#` prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that the `grubenv` file is > 1024 bytes. This is mostly caused by manually editing the file. (e.g. `vi` appends a newline on the last line)

To avoid this, you should never edit grubenv using anything other than `grub-editenv`.

Using `grub-editenv <filename> set exiting_var=existing_value` does not fix the file.

Speculation: You should be able to fix the file by deleting a character or two to get the size back to exactly 1024 bytes. If that does not work, you need to recreate the file using the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/191865/114847) instead. (Get the correct values of the variables using `grub-editenv grubenv list` first and recreate a file with those values)