# Repeating Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue

Tags: bootloader, reboot

During start up I get

Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue...

I have done the steps of the first answer from the following link

[Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191852/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue/259391#259391)

Things are good for one restart. On the second, the grub message comes back. Please let me know if you have an idea of what's going on. Thanks

Comment: This seems to have a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it (at least temporarily):

```
# cd /boot/grub
# rm grubenv
# grub-editenv grubenv create
# grub-editenv grubenv set default=0
# grub-editenv grubenv list
default=0
```

- [Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784).
- [Confirmed working for 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784/comments/56).

Answer (score 0):

For me the above suggested solution only worked in the first place. The error occurred again after the next reboot. I deleted the partition and installed Ubuntu a plenty times but the error always occurred again after a short time.

What really helped was not only to completely reinstall Ubuntu on my SSD, but also to leave some unallocated disc space (for new SSDs about 7%) on the SSD and not formatting the whole space. Since then I never had the error again.