# Error: environment block too small. Press any key to continue

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and getting this error in grub menu

```
Error: environment block too small.
Press any key to continue...
```

I went through this [AskUbuntu Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191852/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue) about this problem but unable to solve it by the answer provided.

I've tried re-installing `grub` and updated it using `sudo update-grub` but error is still there?

Note: I did not find `save_env recordfail` by pressing `e`during boot time GRUB Menu.

Comment: Did you try cleaning up some space and then running `sudo -i` `cd /boot/grub`
`rm grubenv`
`grub-editenv grubenv create`
`grub-editenv grubenv set default=0`
`grub-editenv grubenv list`
`update-grub` after dropping to root in recovery.

Comment: Addititionally, try to do `fsck`. If it also fails, then you'll need to repartition your hard drive.

Comment: Also, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1329794 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1783434 may help, Good Luck. Let me know if one of these works.

Comment: @SharadGautam tried `rm grubenv grub-editenv grubenv` and`create grub-editenv grubenv set default=0` after that `update-grub` as root but I still have to press the key and error message has turned in to purple screen

Comment: Then try to do this:- https://techrax.tk/fixed-ubuntu-reboots-while-booting/

Comment: Recreating "grubenv" file did solve the error I encountered like the OP. My "grubenv" file was manually edited by `vi` and it gave 1025-byte file (instead of original 1024 bytes) because of the newline character appended. Not sure if related.

Comment: It worked for me. Now I nee to figure out why I'm stuck with an 800x600 display resolution.

Comment: @JonnyWong post as answer so OP can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the grubenv

```
sudo rm /boot/grub/grubenv
```

Create a new grubenv

```
sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv create
```

Then reboot