# SSD is wrong before boot to system

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia, ssd

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 six months ago. Everything worked perfectly.

And then I installed Steam and I played a PC game for maybe 3 hours, and powered off my PC at night. The next day, there was a problem when booting my system.

```
Error: Enviroment block too small
```

I tried to find information about how to repair this and I tried to repair it with recovery mode. ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624781/error-environment-block-too-small-press-any-key-to-continue)).

And I had the same problem with Windows (boot problem), then I re-installed and it was working again.

Maybe wrong SSD??

I don't want to reinstall again. Where is the problem?

Thank you for answer.

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26478870/) is log from BootRepair while using an Ubuntu liveCD.

PC:

- SSD Disk Samsung EVO 250GB
- Motherboard ASRock F55
- 12GB RAM (I tried Memory test and was good)
- GPU: GeForce GTX 960
- CPU: Intel Core i5

Answer (score 0):

I tried to some things. 
I found command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`
[More here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1783434)