# message after trying to update grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I see this error when trying to run `update-grub`

```
$ update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 1: /etc/grub.d/10_linux: des: not found
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 2: /etc/grub.d/10_linux: CACHE###libfox-1.6-dev###Fox: not found
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 3: /etc/grub.d/10_linux: CACHE###libfox-1.6-doc###Fox: not found
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 4: /etc/grub.d/10_linux: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: I am glad you posted this as a question. Please do not use edits to answers as a way to write a question.

Comment: Thank you.  I meant - did it solve the problem or just showed the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Did you on purpose, or accidentally, edit the file /etc/10_linux, and especially line 94 which looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY nomodeset"
```

Undo any edits that you made to this file. Any changes that you might want to make to grub should be made at /etc/default/grub. Report back.

Comment: No. I tried to solve the "invalid environment block" problem using this tip:

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/191852/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue/191865#191865?newreg=2e052bcf13bb46e3bb898e6725f1ada4]

Comment: Boot now works OK. I will see what happens during the next boot.

Comment: So far it is fine.

Comment: 10_linux in grub.d folder is not a program - just a text! And it really doesn't look like it should! How it could happen and what could be done?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Please clarify. If you're still having grub error messages, start Synaptic from the dash. Enter "grub" in the search box. For each entry in the list that has a green check box in front of the name, right-click on it and select "Mark for reinstallation". When all of them have been marked as such, click on the Apply icon.

Comment: If I tick a checkbox "download package files only" nothing happens - it returns to the same point in the same way as when I'm trying to apdate the system. If I leave the box empty and just click "apply", it shows this:

> E: Internal Error, No file name for grub-pc:i386

I tried to run fsck from the root on unmounted system - it won't do either. Perhaps nothing could be done until I replace that 10_linux file... I don't know how to do this.

Comment: When I run fsck, it says "clean", but when I check just /etc.grub.d/10_linux it says that "bad magic super block".

Comment: Lets clarify. Where are you seeing "download package files only"? What are you doing when you get the "E:Internal error"? Were you able to reinstall GRUB using Synaptic? What do you mean by "when I check just /etc/grub.d/10_linux"? Are you using "sudo update-grub"? The sudo is required.

Comment: Tick box  "download package files only" I see in the "Summary (as superuser)" window of the Package Manager. If I leave it empty and click "apply" it shows that "Internal error" message. If I tick the box and click "apply", it returns to the initial Synaptic window. Perhaps there are more applications (besides Update and Packet Managers) that can't work without that 10_linux file, but I'm amazed that all other applications are working!  Sudo makes no difference - I see the same messages (in the beginning of this thread).

Comment: I meant that I ran fsck.ext4 just for /etc/grub.d/10_linux in read-only mode when I've got that "bad magic number" message.

Comment: BTW, console also says that " If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device> "

Comment: But I think I need to perform it on unmounted filesystem...

Comment: Boot to a LiveCD, enter terminal, and use one of the e2fsck commands shown above. e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdan, where n is the partition number where Ubuntu is installed.