# Grub hangs at invalid environment error

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I had to force shutdown (by long pressing the start button) Ubuntu 18.04 after the system froze. In such cases usually I would try grub boot loader. A previous solution suggested steps from grub menu ([Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191852/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue)), but in my case even the grub menu is not showing.

Comment: A look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784  (old) shows its usually a result of filesyste corruption.  Maybe boot a 'live' environment (eg. your Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` (file system check) your partitions

Comment: Thanks a lot! booting from live cd and doing a fsck on file system worked.

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark next to the answer below that @guiverc posted. This lets other users knows the answer is the accepted solution. Also click the grey chevron to up-vote the answer. This gives the author 10 more points. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot a live environment (eg. your Ubuntu install media, selecting 'try ubuntu') and do a `fsck` (file system check) of your partitions.

Reboot and it should be okay.

*This is suggested due to a scan of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/439784 (old) which showed the most common cause for this error was file-system corruption.*